# How do you solve for Y?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I know there has got to be a way to solve for $Y$ but I just can't seem to figure it out. Does anyone know how to solve this? Please help :)

$$5(Y(8))=C$$

$$C(Y(4))=B$$

$$B(Y(2))=A$$

$$A(Y(1))=0.50$$

Comment: What are the brackets for?

Comment: I guess they're not needed. It's only to visually show that Y doubles each time it goes up from bottom equation to top equation.

Comment: Isn't $Y$ the same value in all the equations?  What is doubling is a factor that multiplies $Y$.  The first equation could then be written $40Y=C$ and the second $4YC=B$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** Substitute for $C$ from the first to the second equation to get:

$160Y^2 = B$

Then substitute for $B$ into the third equation and so on.

Comment: Thank you for the hint @response but I'm afraid I don't follow you. Can you please explain how to substitute the C?

Comment: $5(Y(8)) = C$ is the same as $40 Y=C$. Substituting, in the second equation, we have: $40 Y (Y(4)) = B$ which simplifies to $160 Y^2=B$. Repeat the above process with the third equation but this time substitute for $B$.

Comment: Ahh! just got the "light bulb" moment. Thank you!!!

Comment: Here's what I did following your advice:

$$40Y=C$$

$$40Y(Y(4))=B$$

$$40Y(Y(4))(Y(2))=A$$

$$40Y(Y(4))(Y(2))(Y(1))=0.50$$

$$(40*4*2*1)(Y*Y*Y*Y)=0.50$$

$$320(Y^4)=0.50$$

$$Y^4=0.0015625$$

$$Y=0.1988176$$

Comment: I did not check the last two steps but it does look right.